# Send mail only if fsockopen is connected to SMTP Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, fsockopen

Trying to be bit defensive in coding, and I am trying to send mail, only if the connection is successful to SMTP server. Currently, I get a `warning` incase if the connection is not successful.

I can still catch if the mail sent is `true` or `false` but I would like to know whats the right way of doing this, so that I am not raising a warning.

Current code :

```
    $this->email->message($content);
    if ($this->email->send()) {
    return true; }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve, so that I dont raise a warning.

```
if fsockopen connection successful {
        if ($this->email->send()) {
        return true; }
        else{
            return false;
        }
}
```

Warning I get now when `fsockopen` is unable to connect.

`Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. )`

Although its working,and I can hide all errors/warnings, I would like the right way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions, PHPMailer does not use `fsockopen` (it uses `stream_socket_client`), and it catches and reports connection errors. I suspect you're using an old version, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and base your code on the examples supplied with it.

Comment: I am sorry, but that tag was accidential. I am using Codeigniter's own mail helper class.